# Symfony2 Doctrine throw NonUniqueResultException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem throwing NonUniqueResultException in my request

```
public function getLastViewUpdate($view)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $result = $qb->select('vu')
        ->from('EasyApp\ApplicationBundle\Entity\ViewUpdate', 'vu')
        ->where('vu.view = :view')
        ->orderBy('vu.date','DESC')
        ->setParameter('view', $view)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();

    return $result;
}
```

But I don't know realy why, I have maybe to import something, but I can't find

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException: "" at /Users/antoine/Documents/projects/easyApp/application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 621
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can check declaration of `getSingleResult` function

```
/**
 * Gets the single result of the query.
 *
 * Enforces the presence as well as the uniqueness of the result.
 *
 * If the result is not unique, a NonUniqueResultException is thrown.
 * If there is no result, a NoResultException is thrown.
 *
 * @param integer $hydrationMode
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NonUniqueResultException If the query result is not unique.
 * @throws NoResultException If the query returned no result.
 */
public function getSingleResult($hydrationMode = null)
{
    ...
    if (count($result) > 1) {
        throw new NonUniqueResultException;
    }
    ...
}
```

To solve the problem You can set `LIMIT` to query and get only one result with `->setMaxResults(1)`.

Comment: Thanks it works but this is not very proper, I don't understand why throwing an error create a critical error

Comment: Its not an error, its exception. check `getSingleResult` code, i updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, but my my page is not fetch and I have a 500 error in symfony

Comment: I have only this "500 Internal Server Error - NonUniqueResultException"

Comment: Simply don't use `getSingleResult` on queries which deliver more than one result. Either limit the query with `->setMaxResults(1)` or use `getResult()` which returns an array of results.

Comment: Looking into this issue.  I have I query like:

$qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

But it still throws the NonUniqueResultException.

Comment: `getOneOrNullResult` can also trigger `NonUniqueResultException`.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `getSingleResult` if you expect more than 1 result... Using this function performs a unicity check of your result, it's the intention of this function.

Many choices :

- Use `getSingleResult` and deal with exception (like a `try {...} catch (NonUniuqueResultException $e) {...}` or adjust your DB structure to avoid duplicates,
- Use `getSingleResult` and add `setMaxResults(1)`, but this is really a strange way to trust your DB model,
- Use `getResult` and do something with returned results.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that you have two or more ViewUpdates with the same view.